# how find an element that does not exist in the first array with javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays that look like this

first array

```js
let arr1 = [
  'FS340089',
  'FS350089',
  'FS360089',
  'FS370089',
]
```

another array

```js
let arr2 = [
  'FS340089',
  'FS350089',
  'FS360089',
  'FS370089',
  'FS380089',
]
```

I would like to get FS380089 at the output

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: loop trough second array and search each item in first array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
let arr3 = arr2.filter(x => arr1.indexOf(x) == -1);
console.log(arr3); // ["FS380089"]
```

It works by iterating through the second array and excluding values that are already in the first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the find() & includes() methods:

```js
let arr1 = [
  'FS340089',
  'FS350089',
  'FS360089',
  'FS370089',
]

let arr2 = [
  'FS340089',
  'FS350089',
  'FS360089',
  'FS370089',
  'FS380089'
]

let result = arr2.find(x => !arr1.includes(x))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution would resolve your problem by covering the case where the array length are different :

```js
let arr1 = [
  'FS340089',
  'FS350089',
  'FS360089',
  'FS370089',
]

let arr2 = [
  'FS340089',
  'FS350089',
  'FS360089',
  'FS370089',
  'FS380089'
]

let result = arr2.length > arr1.length ? arr2.find(x => !arr1.includes(x)) :  arr1.find(x => !arr2.includes(x))
console.log(result)
```